# UnsupportedClassVersionError while deploying TCPIP connector in IBM Websphere

Tags: java, tcp, websphere, connector

I'm trying to deploy a TCPIP connector in the form of an ear in IBM Websphere. But I have no idea what is going wrong here.

WAS version : 8.5
As WAS version uses java 6 by default I tried changing it to java 7 as the jar files my ear uses have been compiled using JAVA 7 - **1.7**

But still It didn't work. While starting the app I get the following error:

```
[3/11/21 16:45:11:905 IST] 0000006b RALifeCycleMa E   J2CA0143E: Embedded ResourceAdapter initialization failed due to Exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: J2CA0128E: An Exception occurred while trying to start ResourceAdapter custtcpip.custtcpip. The exception is: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/my_corp/ci/fiusb/tcpip/FIUsbTCPIPServer
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.resourceProviderEvent(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:907)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl$ResourceEventListenerFilterProxy.resourceProviderEvent(ResourceMgrImpl.java:2208)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.notifyResourceEventListeners(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1622)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1518)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1462)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.start(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1382)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:971)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1249)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:77)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1243)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1081)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$QueuedWork.run(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1981)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
```

I have been banging my head around this for a while.

Comment: Do not longer use java6 or 7 they are outdated since decades

Comment: @Jens I will take a note of that. Do you know how this error can be fixed?